# How to view all the ratings of an app on itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

On itunes connect how can I view the aggregate of rating of an app? It only displays the rating of the last version. Changing the version only filters the reviews

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where to find it in the itunesconnect portal. However, you can use the below link to get the detail of the app with the specified AppID.

1. Open your browser and go to `https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=AppIdGoesHere`
2. Download the text.
3. Open the textfile with any text editor.
4. Search for the **averageUserRatingForCurrentVersion** or **averageUserRating** in textfile. The number after that is what you're looking for.

Hope this helps those who'll have the same questions in the future.

Ref: https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/